# Adapt label box size to text length in layout composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, text, dynamic-text

In the layout composer I want to add a title in black text with a white background.

My title will be dynamic and I want the text box ("label" in the composer) to automatically adapt its size in order to fit the text length without needing to manually change its size.

Comment: You simply could move the label out of the map frame?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your title text comes from a given expression (in my case I just took @layout_name)

You can set the Label's Position & Size properties X and Width to depend on your title text expression:

Set `Width` to be something like: `A x length(title string) + B`:

[image]

Set `X` to be something like: `Page middle X coordinate - Width/2`:

[image]

Here you go:
[image]

Comment: thankyou, it's probably the closest solution.
I guess there's no way to have a constant fit as the text length (which is expressed in number of characters I guess) is translated to millimeters or whatever measure i pick which differs from the actual length(text) measure. I notice in fact that with the same multiplier (even x1) a longer text will have a box wich exceed it in length more compared to a shorter text.

Comment: You would need to find the appropriate A factor to have constant margins, I believe.